# How to make Windows 10 Ethernet connection with no gateway a private connection?

Tags: networking, windows-10, ethernet

I'm new to Windows 10 and have troubles finding a way to set one of my Ethernet connections (I only have one active currently) a private connection. This is simply a connection that connects to one of my subnets that is not connected to the internet, has a static IP and does not have a gateway (gateway field in TCP/IP settings is not filled).

How do I make this connection a private connection to allow files and folders sharing? It would seem the only workaround is to give it an invalid gateway to force Windows 10 to bring up the flyout that allows you to choose if you want to make the PC "discoverable" over that connection. So why am I not allowed to set the connection as private when it doesn't have a gateway?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found the solution:

1. Press Windows key + r and type secpol.msc.
2. Now click on Network list manager policy.
3. Double click on Network in the right pane.
4. Here you can manually change the network location from Private to Public and vice versa.

Comment: in my windows server 2016, which acts like a router, Internal Network is called "Unindentified Network", and External network is called just "Network". But thanks, that did the trick!

Comment: Two issues: (1) this policy will apply to ALL unidentified networks, not just the one you want to change. So if you set "unidentified network" to private, and then go connect to another unidentified network somewhere else, it will also come up private. This is probably not what you want.

(2) secpol.msc is not available in Windows 10 Home.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier way, you can do this in Classic Control Panel.

Control Panel - Network and Internet - HomeGroup - Change network location. There is no need to create a homegroup, just choose that you want your PC to be discoverable.

Comment: Homegroup has been removed from Windows 10 as of version 1803 (Oct 26, 2018)